# Scipy Minimize andf Least Square results on parameter covariance matrix

Tags: scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I experience a problem using `scipy.optimize.minimize` to estimate parameter covariance matrix. Here is a small exercise snippet:

```py
import numpy as np

# Dataset
N=20
rng = np.random.default_rng(2022)
ti = 10.0 * rng.random(N)
ti = np.sort(ti)
sigma_e = 1.
e = rng.normal(0, sigma_e, ti.shape)
param_true = np.array([3.5, 1.0])
yi =param_true[1] + param_true[0]*ti +e

#Least SQ estmation
def test(params, X, y):
    X = jnp.c_[ X, np.ones(len(X)) ] 
    residuals = jnp.dot(X, params) - y
    return residuals

res_lsq=scipy.optimize.leastsq(test, jnp.array([0.,0.]), args=(ti,yi), 
Dfun=None, full_output=True, col_deriv=0, ftol=1.49012e-08, 
xtol=1.49012e-08, gtol=0.0, maxfev=0, epsfcn=None, factor=100, diag=None)

print(res_lsq[0]) # parameters
print(res_lsq[1]) # covariance mtx
```

I get

```py
[3.51045968 0.9103981 ]

[[ 0.00432748 -0.02341142]
 [-0.02341142  0.17665437]]
```

that I have validated by an other method. Now using minimize L-BFGS-B

```py
# Minimize 
def lik(params, X, y):
    X = np.c_[ X, np.ones(len(X)) ] 
    residuals = np.dot(X, params) - y
    return np.mean(residuals ** 2)

lik_model = scipy.optimize.minimize(lik, jnp.array([0.,0.]), args=(ti,yi), method='L-BFGS-B',
                     options={'gtol': 1e-6,'disp': False})

print(lik_model.x)
print(lik_model.hess_inv.todense())
```

I get

```py
[3.51045967 0.91039815]

[[ 0.04327373 -0.23411416]
 [-0.23411416  1.76654345]]
```

As you may probably notice, the parameters are very close to the `leastsq` method but the Inverse Hessian coefficients are 10 times bigger.

Does someone can explain me this feature? or is it a bug? or is there conditionning factor of the Hessian that is internally used that I have missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found how to proceed and it may useful for other people, and at first using `sigma_e=1` is masking part of the problem. So, in the above exercise you can set `sigma_e = 3.0`, and proceed
to the replacement

```py
def lik(params, X, y):
    X = np.c_[ X, np.ones(len(X)) ] 
    residuals = np.dot(X, params) - y
    return 0.5*np.sum((residuals/sigma_e) ** 2)
```

to be used with

```py
lik_model = minimize(lik, jnp.array([0.,0.]), args=(ti,yi), method='BFGS', options={'gtol': 1e-6,'disp': False})
```

And

```py
def test(params, X, y):
    X = jnp.c_[ X, np.ones(len(X)) ] 
    residuals = jnp.dot(X, params) - y
    return residuals/sigma_e
```

if you use

```py
res_lsq=scipy.optimize.leastsq(test, jnp.array([0.,0.]), args=(ti,yi), 
Dfun=None, full_output=True, col_deriv=0, ftol=1.49012e-08, 
xtol=1.49012e-08, gtol=0.0, maxfev=0, epsfcn=None, factor=100, diag=None)
```

Then, `res_lsq[1]` and `lik_model.hess_inv` will gives the same results up to numerical uncertainty. (in case you use `L-BFGS-B` then you get the inverse hessian by `lik_model.hess_inv.todense()`. I must confess that I have made 2 mistakes before 1) not scaling by the residuals by `sigma_e`, 2) the use of np.mean() instead of np.sum(). But, I have not yet figure out the need of the 0.5 factor  in the `minimize` case, although it is an indication of the normal distribution factor,  but I do not manage to get it in the code.

Ok, so far so good now I hope you will get the right covariance matrix in your own use-cases.